# How to install this library in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to use this library: https://github.com/linfaxin/MultiRowsRadioGroup in my project, but I have no idea how to do this. Could you give me a hand?

Comment: I didn't realise that is actually normal project. I will try ilikewaffles way now and write later if it will be neceserry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the project in Android Studio build it and move the .aar file from the library build folder to the lib folder of your project. Then you will need to add `compile (name: 'LIBNAME', ext:'aar')` to your module gradle file.

Edit: 
Also you need to add

```
repositories {
      flatDir{ dirs 'libs' }
}
```

Your gradle file should look like this:

```
dependencies { 
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
      compile (name: 'LIBRARY NAME', ext:'aar') 
      ... 
 } 
 repositories { 
      flatDir{ dirs 'libs' } 
 }
```

Comment: http://fotowrzut.pl/tmp/upload/W7TIDDFAXH/1.jpg
What have I done wrong?
I think I edited wrong gradle - build.gradle. Where is module gradle file?

Comment: Try adding `repositories { flatDir { dirs 'libs' } }`. Also try restarting Android Studio if you use an older version.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!